# Accessing S3 subfolders as non root user using S3FS

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

I can mount S3 buckets using S3FS by running:

```
s3fs -o iam_role="myrole" -o use_cache=/tmp/myBucket myBucket /mnt/myBucket -o allow_other
```

However, when I try to navigate inside this bucket, I find that all the folders have the following permissions and hence a regular user can not browse them:

```
d--------- 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 mySubfolder
```

How can I mount a S3 bucket using S3FS using a regular user and allowing him to access the subfolders?

Comment: Which version of s3fs do you use?

Comment: `uid` and `umask` can be passed to s3fs as parameters which allows to configure the owner and permissions for the recursive files/folders